# Javascript start and repeat function upon mouseover & stop repeat upon mouseleave

Tags: javascript, setinterval, mouseover, clearinterval, mouseleave

I am successfully starting an animation upon mouseover, but cannot manage to stop it upon mouseleave:

Start animation:

```
var executed = false; // to execute only once on repeat hover
var startslider = {};

$('#imgBx').mouseover(function(){

if (!executed) { 
    var startslider = setInterval(function(){
    executed = true;  
    rotateSlide();
    }, 1000);
} // end if executed

}); // end mouseover
```

Stop animation:

```
$('#imgBx').mouseleave(function(){
    clearInterval(startslider);
});
```

Comment: You're declaring `var startslider` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring the global variable 'startslider'.

Remove the var from the variable in the mouseover event listener.

```
 startslider = setInterval(function(){
```